# Why grid.appScope.value return undefined in celltemplate

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, celltemplate

In a grid celltemplate, I am trying the get a value which is in the parent scope of a grid like this

```
<div sigef-entrees-sorties="grid.getCellValue(row, col)" 
  type-flux="grid.appScope.typeFlux"/>
```

but `grid.appScope.typeFlux` is undefined. So how can i get this value.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I think that you are trying to access a `parentRow` of `Ui-grid` sub tree.

I was also facing this issue; that `appscope.row` was `undefined`, but I solved it like this:

We have `row.treeLevel` & `row.treeNode.parentRow`. These will give us the 
`TreeLevel` & its Parent Row Object.

This will work to get parent Row.